# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (500,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from keras.datasets import imdb

from keras.models import load_model

deep = load_model('ImdbLSTMtry.h5')

from keras import preprocessing

import numpy as np
(xtrain,ytrain) , (xtest,ytest) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)

xtrain = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(xtrain,maxlen=500)

xtest = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(xtest,maxlen=500)

print(xtest[0].shape)

result = deep.predict(xtest[0])
```

## model Code

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras import preprocessing
max_fea = 10000
mal = 500
(xtrain,ytrain) , (xtest,ytest) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_fea)
xtrain = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(xtrain,maxlen=mal)
xtest = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(xtest,maxlen=mal)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding , Flatten , Dense , SimpleRNN, LSTM, GRU
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(10000,8,input_length=mal))
model.add(GRU(32))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))         model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics['accuracy'])
model.fit(xtrain,ytrain,epochs=1,batch_size=128,validation_split=0.2)
print(xtest[0])
result = model.evaluate(xtest,ytest)
print(result)
model.save('ImdbLSTMtry.h5')
model.summary()
```

I am trying to predict the sentiment analysis from Imdb dataset in keras,i have changed the shape of my input as the shape of my embedded layers is, but though having above error.

Comment: post the model code.

Comment: have you tried deep.predict([xtest[0]]) ?

Comment: @Marco Cerliani yes I have tried it but giving same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with:

```
result = deep.predict(xtest)
```

The method `predict` is designed to predict not just on one sample (in your case `xtest[0]`), but on a whole dataset (`xtest`).

If you only want a prediction on `xtest[0]`, you can do it as follows:

```
result = deep.predict(np.expand_dims(xtest[0], axis=0))
```

Comment: If it worked, you should mark the answer as accepted :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers